# Apply actions when Window created by Qt.createComponent is closed/destroyed

Tags: qt, qml, components, qtquick2

In my project, the user can click a button in homepage to open a new Window (`QtQuick.Window 2.2`). I want the button to be disabled when the Window is created and enabled when it's closed/destroyed.

The **problem** is

- I don't know how to check the Window's status (created/showed/closed/destroyed/...) to use it as indicator and do other needed actions
- How could I  check the status of components created in similar manner

Code sample:

**Homepage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12


Item {

   id: homePageItem
   property var component: null
   property var obj: null

   RoundButton {
        id: windowBtn
        enabled: // some condition
        ...
        ...

        onClicked: {
            component = Qt.createComponent("Window.qml")
            obj = component.createObject(root)
            obj.show()
            // windowBtn.enabled = false

           }
     }
}
```

**Window.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.2


Window {
    width: 600
    height: 600

    ...
    ...

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for signals from the object you created.

Window.qml

```
Window {
    width: 600
    height: 600

    signal closed()   // Create a new signal

    Component.onDestruction: {
        closed()      // Emit your signal when the object is destroyed
    }
}
```

Homepage.qml

```
        onClicked: {
            component = Qt.createComponent("Window.qml")
            obj = component.createObject(root)

            // Create a listener for your signal
            obj.onClosed.connect(()=> { windowBtn.enabled = true })

            obj.show()
            windowBtn.enabled = false
        }
```

Comment: onDestruction is not giving any reaction when the Window is closed (by "x" button). What is also weird is that when using "onClosing" (which gives me invalid property name error) reacts correctly to the signal and connects correctly to the enabled button option.